# Can I translate ADDRESS in a code line?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, windbg

I receive from an application a message like this:
*"The instruction at 0xA.... referenced memory at 0xB..... The memory could not be "written". Click on OK to terminate the program"*

the address 0xA looks valid: 0x10001053. Exe is mapped in memory by default at 0x40000000 and dlls at 0x10000000 so it's in the first loaded dll at offset 1053h.

Does someone knows a method to transform this address into source line ?

Comment: the address 0x10001053 in the .text section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to locate it with the help of a map file. You may need to tweak some of your compiler/linker options to get the map file generated with sufficient detail.

If you are using the MS compiler then you need [/MAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) linker option.

Comment: You can also use dumpbin on an existing .exe, even if it wasn't linked with /map.  The information may be less complete, especially if linked without debug information, but if linked with debug information, it's usually sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an interactive debugger, open the disassembler window and look for the code label that precedes the assembler line. That should correspond to a function in the source code (or to a function that has inlined the code that caused the problem).

Another trick is to use the **call stack** window, that way you could see all calls from the `main` function down to the function that caused the crash.